# is there a way to run storage statistics on a yocto-produced filesystem?

Tags: yocto

I used Yocto to build a filesystem, using a .bbappend of core-image-minimal.  Two questions:

1. how can i figure out which package is taking huge storage space on the rootfs?

   I can't think of a way other than to look into the ${D} of every package and see how big its components are.  There's gotta be a more systematic, and intelligent way to do that.

From what i can decipher from the manifest, there is nothing related to the size of the package that is being included.

Also, removing some of the packages I added using the IMAGE_INSTALL object, seems to remove the package but the end result of the built image doesn't show a change in its size!!

2. I compared the size of a particular .so on the build machine and on the installation device (a vm) and found that the size on the installation device was 20-30% of the original size seen on the build machine.  Any explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) One way is to enable buildhistory, by adding the following to local.con

```
INHERIT += "buildhistory"
BUILDHISTORY_COMMIT = "1"
```

This will create a directory (git repo) buildhistory in your $BUILDDIR. There you'll be able to find e.g.

```
images/$MACHINE/eglibc/$IMAGE/installed-package-sizes.txt
```

That file will give you the sizes of all installed packages.

There are a lot more things you can learn from buildhistory, see [buildhistory introduction](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#maintaining-build-output-quality)

2) Where did you compare the particular .so-file? If it was from the package's ${B} (i.e. where the library is built), it's not surprising, as the installed .so-file will be stripped. The debug information is installed into -deb.rpm (as the debug info is usually useless on the target and the smaller size is of much higher importance).

Comment: thanks @Anders.  I will try the buildhistory approach (which, btw, I have it enabled but didn't think it had anything to do with pkg metrics).  Also, check out my answer with respect to the actual yocto-provided scripts for the exact same function.

Answer (score 0):

With some looking inside the scripts/ subdir and some googling about some of the existing scripts, it turns out that the good people of Yocto do have these scripts properly functioning out of the box:
scripts/tiny/dirsize.py and ksize.py.

dirsize.py will give you a breakdown of pkg sizes for your rootfs; while ksize.py will give you the equivalent info for the kernel.

Comment: Just a quick comment, `scripts/tiny/dirsize.py`, won't give you the sizes of the installed _packages_, but the sizes of the directories on your rootfs. From that, you can of course deduce which package(s) is/are responsible for the largest files...

Comment: @Anders O .. so would the buildhistory approach you suggested, I'd get the sizes of the _installed_ packages?

Comment: Sure, it lists the installed packages and their sizes. Though  the approach you found yourself will work just as well when it comes to shrinking your filesystem.